# Exclude row based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a table called `_01769_jobs`:

[image: _01769_jobs]

From this table, I want to select all of the rows where the `user_id` is not equal to `163084` and the status is equal to `QC_COMPLETE`:

```
SELECT * FROM _01769_jobs WHERE user_id != 163084 AND status = 'QC_COMPLETE';
```

[image: Result of Query]

From here, I want to further refine these results to exclude any entries where the `job_id` is a `job_id` listed in the result of the `blind_qc_get_worked_on_jobs_by_project_by_user` function.

Calling the function results in the following:

```
SELECT * FROM blind_qc_get_worked_on_jobs_by_project_by_user(1769, 163084);
```

[image: result from function call]

I now want to modify my initial query to exclude the rows whose `job_id`'s are returned from the function call.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM _01769_jobs jobs left join blind_qc_get_worked_on_jobs_by_project_by_user(1769, 163084) bqc_jobs on jobs.job_id = bqc_jobs.job_id WHERE jobs.user_id != 163084 AND bqc_jobs.user_id != 163084 AND jobs.status = 'QC_COMPLETE' ;
```

and a few variations but am not quite sure how to get the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most forms of SQL, you would use a `NOT IN` clause for this.

```
SELECT * FROM _01769_jobs 
WHERE user_id != 163084 
  AND status = 'QC_COMPLETE'
  AND job_id NOT IN (
      SELECT job_id
      FROM blind_qc_get_worked_on_jobs_by_project_by_user(1769, 163084)
  )
```

Postgres seems to be no exception - http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/

If you need this for varying `user_id` and `product_id` values, different database engines use different features for this.  Postgres may be able to do it with a *lateral join* - http://blog.heapanalytics.com/postgresqls-powerful-new-join-type-lateral/

If your database engine does not have a lateral-join or cross-apply, you will need to rework and massage the code of the function into your particular `select`.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this answer.  Will mark resolved (in 7 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `not in` or `not exists`:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM _01769_jobs j
WHERE j.user_id <> 163084 AND j.status = 'QC_COMPLETE' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM blind_qc_get_worked_on_jobs_by_project_by_user(1769, 163084) jpu
                  WHERE jpu.jobid = j.job_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `NOT IN`. You should always use `NOT EXISTS`. This is because the `NOT IN` operator has a non-obvious result when nulls are involved. Here's a quick example.

This works:

```
SELECT
    t1.x
FROM (
    VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS t1 (x)
WHERE
    t1.x NOT IN (
        SELECT
            x
        FROM (
            VALUES (2), (4), (6), (8)) AS t2 (x)
    );
 x
---
 1
 3
(2 rows)
```

This doesn't:

```
buy_side=> SELECT
    t1.x
FROM (
    VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS t1 (x)
WHERE
    t1.x NOT IN (
        SELECT
            x
        FROM (
            VALUES (NULL), (4), (6), (8)) AS t2 (x)
    );
 x
---
(0 rows)
```

`NOT IN` works in the right situations, but leads to trouble when you revise the table design or query, or when you copy-and-paste code from a situation where it works to one where it can't. Best to use tools / habits that work in all situations so you don't have to think about footnotes and nuances. Whoever ends up maintaining your code will thank you.

This is one of many helpful recommendations from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This.